# Play framework get array of query string parameters from request.queryString

Tags: scala, playframework, get, query-string

`routes.conf`

```
GET /api/v1/jurisdictions controllers.v1.JurisdictionController.getJurisdictions()
```

`JurisdictionController`

```
  def getJurisdictions() = Action { implicit request =>
      // this is returning None
      val filters = request.queryString.get("filters") 


      val result = jurisdictionService.getJurisdictions()
      Ok(serializer.serialize(result)).as("application/json")
  }
```

Relevant request URI:

`http://localhost:9000/api/v1/jurisdictions?filter[name]=Ryan&filter[number]=333333`

How can I grab this query string `filter`?

Answer (score -1):

You have to create a custom binder this is a Java implementation but it follows the same principle:

```
public class AgeRange implements QueryStringBindable<AgeRange> {
    public Integer from;
    public Integer to;

    //A simple example of the binder’s use binding the :from and :to query string parameters:

    @Override
    public Optional<AgeRange> bind(String key, Map<String, String[]> data) {

        try{
            from = new Integer(data.get("from")[0]);
            to = new Integer(data.get("to")[0]);
            return Optional.of(this);

        } catch (Exception e){ // no parameter match return None
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String unbind(String key) {
        return new StringBuilder()
            .append("from=")
            .append(from)
            .append("&to=")
            .append(to)
            .toString();
    }
}
```

[Java documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/RequestBinders#/conf/routes)

[Scala documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaRequestBinders#QueryStringBindable)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is a scala question

Comment: Updated the answer, the principle and implementation are basically in both languages; have a look into the documentation.